# How to make boardgame for android using flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I want to build a board game using flutter. 
I have already started learning flutter basics and able to create and design the layout for the board.
Currently I am stuck as I am not able to figure out how to make a piece move/animate from one grid to another based on user input.
It will be great if someone can share their experience on this or point me to any already available source for learning this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a game it makes sense to use a custom painter to have more control over the appearance.

So you need:

- A class extending `CustomPainter` that implements the drawing logic.
- A `CustomPaint` widget that makes use of the painter.
- A `GestureDetector` to take care of the piece moves.
- A wrapper class, say `Board`, that ties `CustomPaint` and `GestureDetector` together.
- Some place to store the state. Where exactly to put the state in Flutter is a bit of an art. As a rule you'd want the `Board` widget to be responsible for ephemeral state, such as the ID and the position of the piece that is being currently dragged (because it is used only by the painter and doesn't affect the game state). For the actual game state you may want to use something more permanent. More information on state management in Flutter: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#managing-state, https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple.

Putting it all together:

```dart
class BoardPainter extends CustomPainter {
  // Painting logic.
  ...
}

class Board extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => BoardState();
}

class BoardState extends State<Board> {
  static const double _dragStartTolerance = 50.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onPanStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
              for (final piece in pieces) {
                if ((details.localPosition - piece.pos).distance <
                    _dragStartTolerance) {
                  setState(() {
                    // Drag started. Save piece ID to track it later.
                    ...
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                // Drag in progress. Update piece display position, so that
                // the painter can draw it under the finger. Don't report to
                // the game engine, because the drag hasn't finished yet.
                ...
              }
            },
            onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                // Drag finished. Report to the game engine, which should
                // decide whether the move is valid and update game state
                // accordingly.
                ...
              });
            },
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: BoardPainter(...),
              size: ...
            ),
          );
  }
}
```